# How to export conda env after installing packages using pypy3, to be used with snakemake

Tags: conda, snakemake

I'm using snakemake with conda env.

I created conda environment like `conda create -n myenv some_packages`
after that I used pypy3 to install other packages, like.
`pypy3 -m some_package
 pypy3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir some_package`

Now I exported the env in this way `conda env export > myenv.yaml`

But when the yaml file used by snakemake it does not install the packages that were installed using `pypy3`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: preferably you don't mix different environment managars. Can you install the package with conda as well?

Comment: Do you mean instead of `pypy3 -m some_package` I should use `conda install some_package`. It is a good suggestion, but the conda environment has the Pypy3 intepreter installed, but one Pypy3 package `intervaltree` is still missing. The reason why this is not installed by default is that this is not yet available in any conda repositories. as a result I used `pypy3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir intervaltree==3.0.2`

Comment: I actually never heard of pypy3 before, and I thought it was something like pip! I am not sure how to do this. You could always try to add it to for instance conda-forge and then it will be conda installable.

Comment: Would it be okay for you to manually add the entries in the myenv.yaml?

Comment: I will try that, and see if it will work.